# Angular 2 unit testing component, mocking ContentChildren

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, angular

I am implementing a wizard component in Angular 2 RC4, and now I am trying to write som unit tests. Unit testing in Angular 2 is starting to get well documented, but I simply cannot find out how to **mock the result of a content query** in the component.

The app has 2 components (in addition to the app component), WizardComponent and WizardStepComponent. The app component (app.ts) defines the wizard and the steps in its template:

```
 <div>
  <fa-wizard>
    <fa-wizard-step stepTitle="First step">step 1 content</fa-wizard-step>
    <fa-wizard-step stepTitle="Second step">step 2 content</fa-wizard-step>
    <fa-wizard-step stepTitle="Third step">step 3 content</fa-wizard-step>
  </fa-wizard>
</div>
```

The WizardComponent (wizard-component.ts) gets a reference to the steps by using a ContentChildren query.

```
@Component({
selector: 'fa-wizard',
template: `<div *ngFor="let step of steps">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
          </div>
          <div><button (click)="cycleSteps()">Cycle steps</button></div>`

})
export class WizardComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ContentChildren(WizardStepComponent) steps: QueryList<WizardStepComponent>;
....
}
```

The problem is how to mock the steps variable in the unit test:

```
describe('Wizard component', () => {
  it('should set first step active on init', async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return tcb
    .createAsync(WizardComponent)
    .then( (fixture) =>{
        let nativeElement = fixture.nativeElement;
        let testComponent: WizardComponent = fixture.componentInstance;

        //how to initialize testComponent.steps with mock data?

        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(fixture.componentInstance.steps[0].active).toBe(true);
    });
  })));
});
```

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xwDLZbGJP5TbkwO7RX9n?p=preview) implementing a very simple wizard demonstrating the problem. The wizard-component.spec.ts file contains the unit test.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks to [drewmoore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988693/drewmoore)'s answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654834/angular2-unit-test-with-input) question, I have been able to get this working.

The key is to create a wrapper component for testing, which specifies the wizard and the wizard steps in it's template. Angular will then do the content query for you and populate the variable.

**Edit: Implementation is for Angular 6.0.0-beta.3**

My full test implementation looks like this:

```
  //We need to wrap the WizardComponent in this component when testing, to have the wizard steps initialized
  @Component({
    selector: 'test-cmp',
    template: `<fa-wizard>
        <fa-wizard-step stepTitle="step1"></fa-wizard-step>
        <fa-wizard-step stepTitle="step2"></fa-wizard-step>
    </fa-wizard>`,
  })
  class TestWrapperComponent { }

  describe('Wizard component', () => {
    let component: WizardComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestWrapperComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
        declarations: [
          TestWrapperComponent,
          WizardComponent,
          WizardStepComponent
        ],
      }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestWrapperComponent);
      component = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;
    });

    it('should set first step active on init', () => {
      expect(component.steps[0].active).toBe(true);
      expect(component.steps.length).toBe(3);
    });
  });
```

If you have better/other solutions, you are very welcome to add you answer as well. I'll leave the question open for some time.

Comment: I had a similar issue and came across your question. After searching a little more myself I found a post where they say you can Do all of this now with the TestBed class of @angular/core/testing by using TestBed.createComponent(TypeOfComponent). Maybe this might be a help for other people with the same problem.

Comment: I just want to highlight the crucial part which is the SUT (`wizardComponentInstance`) reference.

Comment: I tried the exact same way. However, my steps in the component is still empty. Any ideas?

Comment: thx worked like a gem

Answer (score 7):

For anybody coming to this question recently, things have changed slightly and there is a different way to do this, which I find a bit easier. It is different because it uses a template reference and  `@ViewChild` to access the component under test rather than `fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance`. Also, the syntax has changed.

Let's say we have a select component that requires an option template to be passed in. And we want to test that our `ngAfterContentInit` method throws an error if that option template is not provided.

Here is a minimal version of that component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-select',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-template
        *ngFor="let option of options"
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="optionTemplate"
        [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: option}">
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MySelectComponent<T> implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() options: T[];
  @ContentChild('option') optionTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (!this.optionTemplate) {
      throw new Error('Missing option template!');
    }
  }
}
```

First, create a `WrapperComponent` which contains the component under test, like so:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <my-select [options]="[1, 2, 3]">
      <ng-template #option let-number>
        <p>{{ number }}</p>
      </ng-template>
    </my-select>
  `
})
class WrapperComponent {
  @ViewChild(MySelectComponent) mySelect: MySelectComponent<number>;
}
```

Note the use of the `@ViewChild` decorator in the test component. That gives access to `MySelectComponent` by name as a property on the `TestComponent` class. Then in the test setup, declare both the `TestComponent` and the `MySelectComponent`.

```
describe('MySelectComponent', () => {
  let component: MySelectComponent<number>;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WrapperComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      /* 
         Declare both the TestComponent and the component you want to 
         test. 
      */
      declarations: [
        TestComponent,
        MySelectComponent
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WrapperComponent);

    /* 
       Access the component you really want to test via the 
       ElementRef property on the WrapperComponent.
    */
    component = fixture.componentInstance.mySelect;
  });

  /*
     Then test the component as normal.
  */
  describe('ngAfterContentInit', () => {
     component.optionTemplate = undefined;
     expect(() => component.ngAfterContentInit())
       .toThrowError('Missing option template!');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I think where you have `TestComponent` you mean `WrapperComponent`.  Also, I had to add `fixture.detectChanges()` after component assigment ([ref](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-dom-testing))

Answer (score -1):

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'test-cmp',
        template: `<wizard>
                    <wizard-step  [title]="'step1'"></wizard-step>
                    <wizard-step [title]="'step2'"></wizard-step>
                    <wizard-step [title]="'step3'"></wizard-step>
                </wizard>`,
    })
    class TestWrapperComponent {
    }

    describe('Wizard Component', () => {
        let component: WizardComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestWrapperComponent>;
        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [SharedModule],
                schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
                declarations: [TestWrapperComponent]
            });
        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestWrapperComponent);
            component = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });

        describe('Wizard component', () => {
            it('Should create wizard', () => {
                expect(component).toBeTruthy();
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written