# Unit test with Jest on Angular gives me this error: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined where undefined is an observable

Tags: angular, jestjs

Here the method I want to test. It´s the ngOnInit lifecicle

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editable.subscribe((data) => {
        this.enableEdition = data.enabled;
    });
}
```

Here my test:

```
it('ngOnInit', () => {
    const editableMock = of({ enabled: false });
    component.editable = editableMock;
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.enableEdition).toBe(false);
});
```

I am getting this error:
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined*

[image]

Maybe the problem is coming from the way the editable is sending to .ts from another component and the setTimeout where the first emision of the observable is located:

The subject which is the source of the observable is localted on table component which is a sibling of table-action component and the observable is shared from table to table-action this way:

Parent template:

```
    <table-actions
      [editable]="_editableState">
    </table-actions>

    <table>
    </table>
```

parent get the subject from table component using a viewChild and then share it to table-action using an input

Parent.ts

```
  @ViewChild('table', { static: true })
  murTable!: MurTableComponent;

  public _editableState!: Observable<any>;

  this._editableState = this.murTable.stateEditing.asObservable();
```

First emision of the subject is located within a setTimeout(). Maybe this produce an asynchrony error

table.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.onFirstDataRendered(null);
    this.stateEditing.next({ enabled: !!this.editType });
  }, 1500);
```

}

Comment: Your test works for me. You are sure this fails for you?

Comment: If I move `component.ngOnInit();` up before `const editableMock = of({ enabled: false });` I am getting the same error.

Comment: Yes I am getting error: what jest, angular and node version you have?

Comment: I have "jest": "^27.0.4", node v16.13.2 and "@angular/core": "^12.0.3",

Comment: I tried with the current Angular CLI versions and Node v16.13.2

Comment: How do you initiate `this.editable` in your component?

Comment: Could this be triggered by a different `ngOnInit` call originating, say, in a `beforeEach` section?

Comment: this.editable is initiate like this @Input() editable!: Observable<any> because it´s comming from sibling component table as I explained

Comment: ngOnInit is only called inside this test. There is nothing related with ngOnInit inside beforeEach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 unit test with @Input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654834/angular2-unit-test-with-input)

Comment: "ngOnInit is only called inside this test" - I believe `fixture.detectChanges()` also triggers hooks like ngOnInit and ngOnChanges.

Comment: Calling fixture.detectChanges() tells Angular to run change-detection. Finally! Every time it is called, it updates data bindings like ng-if, and re-renders the component based on the updated data. Calling this function will cause ngOnInit to run only the first time it is called.  https://medium.com/@menloinnovations/testing-asynchronous-operations-in-angular-components-45d1ebad3864

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

If I place the observable mock and its assignment before the fixture.detectChanges() located on my 2º beforeEach(), it works.

```
describe('MurTableActionsComponent', () => {
 let component: MurTableActionsComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<MurTableActionsComponent>;


beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [AgGridModule],
  providers:[ MurPrintService ],
  declarations: [TableActionsComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
.compileComponents()
});

 beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TableActionsComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;


  const editableMock = of({ enabled: false });
  component.editable = editableMock;

  fixture.detectChanges();
  })
```

Now my test has this form:

```
it('ngOnInit', () => {
component.ngOnInit();

expect(component.enableEdition).toBe(false);
```

});